# Programa não executa ao preencher vetor com números randômicos não repetidos em C

Tags: c, c++, c++11, dev-c++, c++14

Estou tentando fazer com que o números randômicos sejam gerados e preencher um vetor em uma função separada, porém o programa não executa e trava se eu colocar um número alto, e nem tão alto, como 50 ou 100. Abaixo segue meu código, se alguém souber o que está errado me ajuda aí, pfv.

```
#include<time.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

//variáveis globais
int tamanho = 0;

//links das funções
int menuPrincipal();
int retornaTamanho();
void preencheVetor(int tamanhoVetor, int *vetor);

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int opcao = 0, vetor[tamanho];

    do{
        opcao = menuPrincipal();

        switch(opcao){
        case 0:
            printf("\n ----------- APLICAÇÃO ENCERRADA! ----------- \n");
            exit(0);
            break;
        case 1:
            tamanho = retornaTamanho();

            printf("\n Tamanho do Vetor = %d \n", tamanho);

            preencheVetor(tamanho, vetor);

            break;
        default:
            printf("\n ----------- OPÇÃO INVÁLIDA ----------- \n\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
    }while(true);

    return 0;
}

int menuPrincipal(){
    int opcaoMenu = 0;

    printf("\n ------------ MENU ------------ \n");
    printf("\n ESCOLHA O MÉTODO DE ORDENAÇÃO: \n");
    printf("\n 1 - BUBBLE SORT \n");
    printf("\n 2 - SELECT SORT \n");
    printf("\n 3 - INSERT SORT \n");
    printf("\n 0 - SAIR \n");
    printf("\n DIGITE SUA OPÇÃO = ");
    scanf("%d", &opcaoMenu);

    system("cls");

    return opcaoMenu;
}

int retornaTamanho(){
    int opcaoTamanho = 0, valorTamanho = 0;

    printf("\n ------- TAMANHO DO VETOR -------- \n");
    printf("\n ESCOLHA O TAMANHO DO VETOR: \n");
    printf("\n 1 - 100 \n");
    printf("\n 2 - 10.000 \n");
    printf("\n 3 - 100.000 \n");
    printf("\n 4 - 1.000.000 \n");
    printf("\n 0 - VOLTAR \n");
    printf("\n DIGITE SUA OPÇÃO = ");
    scanf("%d", &opcaoTamanho);

    system("cls");

    switch(opcaoTamanho){
    case 0:
        main();
        break;
    case 1:
        valorTamanho = 100;
        break;
    case 2:
        valorTamanho = 10000;
        break;
    case 3:
        valorTamanho = 100000;
        break;
    case 4:
        valorTamanho = 1000000;
        break;
    default:
        retornaTamanho();
        break;
    }

    return valorTamanho;
}

void preencheVetor(int tamanhoVetor, int *vetor){
    int randomico = 0;

    bool numExistente = false;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoVetor; i++){

        randomico = (int) rand() % tamanhoVetor;

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if(randomico == vetor[j]){
                numExistente = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!numExistente){
            vetor[i] = randomico;
        }else{
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você cria um vetor de jeito estático (sem usar `malloc` ou coisas do gênero), seu tamanho é fixo definido na hora da criação da variável.

Tente mudar seu código para algo mais ou menos assim :

```
#define MAX 1000000
/* código omitido */

int main() {
    int vetor[MAX];
    /* o resto do código */
    return 0;
}
```

Desse jeito, o vetor será criado com o tamanho `MAX` (um milhão) e não ocorrerá problemas com seu tamanho do contexto do seu código

Comment: Obrigado por responder! Mas @JeffersonQuesado, esse tamanho do vetor vai variar de acordo com o que o usuário definir na função retornaTamanho(), pois eu preciso fazer testes com vários tamanhos de valores, pra minha avaliação. Como eu faria, então?

Comment: O vetor só é criado uma vez. Portanto, ele vai assumir o valor `tamanho` do início do código, que é garantidamente 0. Esse é um exemplo de vetor estático, não de vetor dinâmico. Para vetores dinâmicos, você vai precisar mexer com alocação de memória, que é um tópico um pouco pposterior ao uso de memória estática  ;-)

Comment: Acho que entendi. Então terei que utilizar aquela função malloc?

Comment: Você está começando a programar agora, não é? Eu sugiro que se acostume com alocação estática e escopo de variáveis antes de enveredar no caminho do `malloc`

Comment: Mais ou menos. Estou mexendo com C agora por conta da faculdade. Mas já programei com C# e Delphi (Object Pascal), mas lá não tinham essas coisas.

Comment: Pode ser interessante caso queira se aprofundar : http://wiki.icmc.usp.br/images/5/59/Aula14-AlocacaoDinamica.pdf https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/aloca.html

Comment: Valeu, amigão! Vou dar uma sacada. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Qualquer upvote é bem vindo o/